# Unable to create Maven Projects and unable to download maven dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am unable to create Maven projects and none of the dependencies are getting downloaded. Whenever I am creating new project, I am receiving below error screenshot:

[Eclipse Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efpFE.png)

Also, none of the maven commands are working, like **mvn clean**. Getting below error:

[Maven Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfZXM.png)

Comment: Then you probably have a problem with your network/firewall/proxy.

Comment: I am not using proxy currently...and also I am able to access maven repository(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/) from browser.

Comment: Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections and make sure you have selected Direct active provider

Comment: @EugenCovaci made changes...still issue persist.

Comment: Did you restart Eclipse after changing network settings?

Comment: @EugenCovaci yes did that too...still no luck..
It was working few days back...no idea what went wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

This is usually a sign that someone or something is intercepting HTTPS traffic, and is messing with the certification path.

I have this problem with my company's network because our Cyber team use a magic HTTPS sniffing tool that replaces the certificate of the site you're trying to access with the company's certificate so that traffic can be monitored. (Forgive my noddy explanation)

**If you're not behind a corporate proxy or a proxy owned by someone who you know manages your internet connection, then you may have security issues that are way beyond the scope of what I'm explaining here!**

Anyway, the solution for me was to go to the URL maven is trying to download from (in your case, https://repo.spring.io ) and download the certificate from your web browser (this varies by browser type, but you can google 'how to download certificate from *mybrowser*.

You can then add that certificate to your local JDK certificate store. Here are the Oracle instructions for installing a root CA in your truststore: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19906-01/820-4916/geygn/index.html